# RPi3 connecting to WEP router using Python

Tags: python, wifi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to connect to WiFi networks using Python, but hitting a dead end.

I'm using the wireless module in Python: https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/wireless

```
from wireless import Wireless

wireless = Wireless()
wireless.connect(ssid, password)
```

However, this seems to only work for WPA and WPA2 routers.

I've also looked to see if I can do it via the terminal (so then I could call it in Python): https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid SSID key PASSWORD
```

However, this doesn't seem to connect to the router either.

So I was wondering whether anyone knows how to connect to a WEP router, or if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What O/S are you using? Can you connect to it from the RaspPi3 built-in wireless options?

If so - what are settings in wpa_supplicant?

From the library notes - this might be an answer:

> To use wpa_supplicant, network-manager (the backend for nmcli) must
>   not be running. This is because network-manager runs an instance of
>   wpa_supplicant behind the scenes which will conflict with the
>   wpa_supplicant instance that this library would create. If you have a
>   network-manager on your machine but would prefer to use wpa_supplicant
>   (not recommended), run sudo service network-manager stop before using
>   wireless

Comment: Hi, sorry for the later reply. I'm using Raspbian Lite. The wpa_supplicant settings are default (I haven't changed them) and I don't have nmcli installed.
As for using the built-in wireless options, since the OS is only a terminal, I've tried `iwconfig wlan0 essid SSID key PASSWORD`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Gotta admit I gave up quickly trying to setup wireless on Lite - mine is WPA/WPA2 though. Not much support for WEP anymore. Does your Wireless show up using `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` . If so - what does it look like beside the IE setting?

Comment: Also - what does it say in your current file: copy/paste from `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and show the values after `network={`